# $\cos(y\,\operatorname{acosh}(\exp(x)))$ is real for all real $x,y$

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-functions, trigonometry

$\cos(y\,\operatorname{acosh}(\exp(x)))$ is real for all real $x,y$ even though $\operatorname{acosh}$ is complex for $x<1$. I found it empirically but still can't prove it yet. Can someone please offer or point me to a proof? My search yielded nothing though it is hard to believe that this result isn't published.

Obviously I already tried Euler's formula and the logarithmic representation of inverse hyperbolic functions. They didn't help yet.

To see a *normalized* plot of this function on Wolfram Alpha click [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%28y*acosh%28exp%28x%29%29%29%20%2F%20%28y*cosh%28pi%2F2%29%29%20x%20in%20%5B-pi*4%2Cpi*4%5D%20y%20in%20%5B-2%2C2%5D)

Comment: $$\cos(\mathrm{acosh}(-2))\approx 
  2.910985563
-11.1786674 i$$

Comment: hmm i tried it with wxmaxima

Comment: @gammatester, thanks for the comment, i edited the question. indeed i forgot a detail: cos(acosh(x)) is real for x>-1, while we'd expect it to be defined on the real line for x>1

Comment: On 0<x<1, acosh(x) is pure imaginary. Writing cos(x) as (exp(ix)+exp(-ix))/2, you can see the result will still be real on this interval.

Comment: @rundavidrun thanks, nice observation. still can you prove that acosh(x) is pure imaginary for 0<x<1?

Comment: The only non-trival part for your original questions is  the range $-1<x<1$. Here you have 
$$\mathrm{arccosh}(x)= \ln(x+\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt{x+1})=\ln(x+i\sqrt{1-x^2})=i \arccos(x)$$
and therefore
$$\cos(\mathrm{arccosh}(x))=\cos(i\arccos(x))=\cosh(\arccos(x)),$$
which is real for all $x\in (-1,1)$.

Comment: @gammatester very nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x \in\mathbb{R}$ we have $e^x>0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and, $0<e^x<1$ for $x<0$  and $e^x\ge 1$ for $x \ge 0$. So, for $x \ge 0$ $\mbox{acosh}( e^x) \in \mathbb{R}$ and, if $y \in \mathbb{R}$, also $\cos (y \,\mbox{acosh}( e^x)) \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $x<0$ and  $0<e^x<1$ than $\mbox{acosh}( e^x)$ is a pure imaginary number and, since $\cos iz=\cosh z \in \mathbb{R}$ for $z\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $\cos (y \,\mbox{acosh}( e^x)) \in \mathbb{R}$.